# Impact of removing a list item on reversed() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

As far as I know, `reversed()` function gives an iterator and works just like `iter()` but will give the items in reverse order. However I faced a strange behavior from the object that gets back from `reversed()` function.

By looking at:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
iter_lst = iter(lst)
lst.remove('c')
print(list(iter_lst))
```

output : `['a', 'b', 'd']`

It's just as expected. but:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
rev_iter_lst = reversed(lst)
lst.remove('c')
print(list(rev_iter_lst))
```

output : `[]`

Shouldn't it be : `['d', 'b', 'a']` ?

Is it something in implementation of `__reversed__()` method in list object or `__next__()` method in the iterator object that prevents this ? I mean if something changes in original list it won't produce reverse sequence maybe...

**Update**: I've posted an answer which is a possible fix to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68313922/13944524), I've tested that but I'm unaware if there is a situation that this implementation would give unexcepted result.

Comment: Basic rule: never change the list you are iterating over!

Comment: @KlausD. That's true, I asked just for curiosity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to `list.__reversed__` [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/15f0fc571c1fbc84b6b74dfeb373ca3d35e4c5d7/Objects/listobject.c#L3293), the iterator remembers the last index address and returns the iterator which remembers the last index address.
now when you remove an item it will shift all the indexes and makes the last address point to nowhere and it will return an empty list because there is nothing to iterate over.
let me describe more:
consider following list: `lst = ['a','b','c']`
also let's assume `lst[0]` is at the 100 and each character is one byte so, the character `'c'` is in the 102.
when you create a revered iterator it will remember 102 as the start point.
in the next step, we omit `'b'` now the character `'c'` is in address 101.
and when you ask the iterator to iterate, it will start to look at position 102. what it will found there? literally nothing and obviously it will return an empty list.

I hope this can be helpful :)

> EDIT: the word address is not correct. I must use index instead...

Comment: Thanks, this is how it seems to work. but could you tell which line of this source code says if an item is removed then return an empty list. Is it that difficult to regenerate the last index of the list from it's length ?

Comment: i have added more details in my answer,@SorousHBakhtiary

Comment: Sequence types like list, store the size of the object in an attribute. Whenever `append()` or `remove()` methods get called, they change that attribute. So Python can easily figure out the last item position in the list. In case `'b'` removed, that attribute decreased to 2. That shouldn't be a problem. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: im not sure about this answer, but I think implementing such idea may cause some ambiguities.condsider this code:
```
lst = ['a','b','c',d']
rev = reversed(a)
print(rev.__next__())
a.pop(2)
print(list(rev))
```
now what? should we re-print the 'd'? or should we continue from 'b'?

Comment: Since it's implemented that it should take items from the original list,  then it should re-print `'d'`. This wouldn't happen in normal cases. Because we dynamically changed the index and order of the items, of course this results could happen. In fact this is the way python handles this situation. e.g. We're gonna see infinite loop if we iterate over a list and append to it at the same time.

Comment: This is somewhat misleading. Just because it doesn't find something there doesn't mean it'll have to return an empty list. Just like `['a', 'b', 'd'][99::-1]` doesn't return an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

So after the discussion with @kkasra12 I ended up implementing Python's pseudo-list object (without doing all the necessary checkings) to mimic it's behavior and I just focused on reverse() operation. Here is my class:

```
class MyList:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.length = n
        self._seq = list(range(n))

    @property
    def seq(self):
        return self._seq

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._seq[item]

    def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
        self._seq[idx] = value

    def __reversed__(self):
        return ReverseIterator(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._seq)

    def append(self, v):
        self._seq.append(v)
        self.length += 1

    def remove(self, v):
        self._seq.remove(v)
        self.length -= 1
```

And my `ReverseIterator`:

```
class ReverseIterator:
    def __init__(self, org):
        self.org = org
        self._index = org.length

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if 0 < self._index:
            try:
                item = self.org.seq[self._index - 1]
                self._index -= 1
                return item
            except IndexError:
                raise StopIteration()
        else:
            raise StopIteration()
```

The result:

```
obj = MyList(6)
iter_obj = iter(obj)
obj.remove(2)
print(list(iter_obj))

print('-----------------------')

obj = MyList(6)
rev_iter_obj = reversed(obj)
obj.remove(2)
print(list(rev_iter_obj))
```

output :

```
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5]
-----------------------
[]
```

By commenting those `remove` statements above, we can see that it works like original `list` object.

Then I created new `SmartReverseIterator` iterator which can handle if an item is removed from the original object and can generate the values on the fly just like how `iter()` wokred on the list in OP.

The only thing should be considered is if an item is removed(`self._index` would be smaller than original object's length), the `self._index` should be reset.

```
class SmartReverseIterator:
    def __init__(self, org):
        self.org = org
        self._index = org.length

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if 0 < self._index:
            try:
                item = self.org.seq[self._index - 1]
                return item

            except IndexError:
                self._index = self.org.length
                item = self.org.seq[self._index - 1]
                return item

            finally:
                self._index -= 1
        else:
            raise StopIteration()
```

By changing the `__reversed__` method on `MyList` to return this new iterator, the result is going to be:

```
obj = MyList(6)
iter_obj = iter(obj)
obj.remove(2)
print(list(iter_obj))

print('-----------------------')

obj = MyList(6)
rev_iter_obj = reversed(obj)
obj.remove(2)
print(list(rev_iter_obj))
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5]
-----------------------
[5, 4, 3, 1, 0]
```

I wanted to know if there is any downside to this, or in other words why python decided not to implement `__reversed__` method on `list` objects like this to result exactly how iter() can generate values if an item is removed.

In which situation we would see issues ?

Comment: Excellent this is so nice

Answer (score 1):

The `list` call will iterate the reverse iterator, whose `index < PyList_GET_SIZE(seq)` check [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/15f0fc571c1fbc84b6b74dfeb373ca3d35e4c5d7/Objects/listobject.c#L3340) will fail because you shrunk `seq` in the meantime, and thus won't yield a value but stop:

```
listreviter_next(listreviterobject *it)
{
    (some checks)
    index = it->it_index;
    if (index>=0 && index < PyList_GET_SIZE(seq)) {
        (decrease the index and return the element)
    }
    (stop the iteration)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still having doubt that why they decided not to provide the approach [which I've provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68313922/13944524) what would be the issues ? retrieving the new list's length is not hard.

Comment: I guess they didn't want to explicitly support such "bad" usage. You could try to track down how that check got in there and hope that the author left some remark :-)